# What makes grep consider a file to be binary?

Tags: grep

I have some database dumps from a Windows system on my box. They are text files. I'm using cygwin to grep through them. These appear to be plain text files; I open them with text editors such as notepad and wordpad and they look legible. However, when I run grep on them, it will say `binary file foo.txt matches`.

I have noticed that the files contain some ascii `NUL` characters, which I believe are artifacts from the database dump.

So what makes grep consider these files to be binary? The `NUL` character? Is there a flag on the filesystem? What do I need to change to get grep to show me the line matches?

Comment: `--null-data` may be useful if `NUL` is the delimiter.

Answer (score 174, accepted):

If there is a `NUL` character anywhere in the file, grep will consider it as a binary file.

There might a workaround like this `cat file | tr -d '\000' | yourgrep` to eliminate all null first, and then to search through file.

Comment: ... or use `-a`/`--text`, at least with GNU grep.

Comment: @derobert: actually, on some (older) systems, grep see lines, but its output will truncate each matching line at the first `NUL` (probably becauses it calls C's printf and gives it the matched line?). On such a system a `grep cmd .sh_history` will return as many empty lines as there are lines matching 'cmd', as each line of sh_history has a specific format with a `NUL` at the begining of each line. (but your comment "at least on GNU grep" probably comes true. I don't have one at hand right now to test, but I expect they handle this nicely)

Comment: +1 for using -a / --text with GNU grep, because you can mix this easily with recursive search, e.g. 

`egrep -r -a mystring .`

Thanks @derobert

Comment: Is the presence of a NUL character the only criteria? I doubt it. It's probably smarter than that. Anything falling outside the Ascii 32-126 range would be my guess, but we'd have to look at the source code to be sure.

Comment: My info was from the man page of the specific grep instance. Your comment about implementation is valid, source trumps docs.

Comment: I had a file which `grep` on cygwin considered binary because it had a long dash (0x96) instead of a regular ASCII hyphen/minus (0x2d). I guess this answer resolved the OP's issue, but it appears it is incomplete.

Comment: Thnx for the comment. I hadn't realized that different platform would handle the issue differently.

Comment: Not true, grep will work with the file each line as string but will stop after the first NUL coincidence. Take a look on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50992292/grep-not-parsing-the-whole-file

Comment: MiguelOrtiz and cp.engr could be right. In Windows Subsystem for Linux, grep treat any file that contains Chinese characters as binary file. While grep in MobaXterm considers Chinese characters as plain text. Both of them treat `NUL` or `\0` as binary file.

Comment: I have used grep with utf-8, so it can handle long dash in utf-8. It may depend on local. It is definitely not a file system flag.

Comment: BSD grep (which is available on MacOS) also supports `-a` / `--text`

Comment: doing cat, pipe, tr, pipe AGAIN... seems like a whole lot of wasted resources... when you can just use `grep --text` option... and not use up lots of extra cpu and memory (two processes, two pipes).

Comment: This answer is the only one that worked on my Ubuntu 20 for a seemingly innocent log file that had `NUL` characters. Also, as mentioned by other comments to this answer, `grep --text -i <search string> <file name>` works great too.

Comment: @MichaelMartinez  : `Anything falling outside the Ascii 32-126 range would be my guess` …….. ehhh….. you do realize the typical newline `\n` (or `\r\n` in `Windows`) already falls out of your range criteria ? (and the horizontal tab `( 0x9 :: \11 :: \t )` too)

Comment: @RAREKpopManifesto you get the gist of my comment, right? In any case this is easily testable: `echo Ascii > ./testfile; grep A ./testfile; dd if=/dev/zero of=./testfile bs=1 seek=5 count=2; grep A ./testfile`

Comment: @MichaelMartinez : i'm not saying `\0` is a false criteria. If it were I'd be more concerned about `grep` itself. I'm merely saying your suggested filtering criteria might be overly broad, even without looking at `grep` source, and that plenty of `ASCII` bytes, even with no consideration of `Unicode`, would exist in any properly formatted `"text"` file

Comment: (I put **text** in quotes cuz I'll let others philosophically debate whether something like a `.mp4` file comprised of just a single stream of subtitles using only `ASCII 32-126` chars constitute a text file or not, cuz it's easily extractable with a text-oriented parser despite being wrapped in a binary container)

Answer (score 170):

`grep -a` worked for me:

```
$ grep --help
[...]
 -a, --text                equivalent to --binary-files=text
```

Comment: This is the best, least expensive answer IMO.

Comment: But not POSIX compliant

Comment: Would you mind to explain why it is not? It would be good to make it clear, for all of us who find this answer as an option. Thanks :).

Comment: Hey I've come here a SECOND time to relearn this LOL. A French accent (diacritic) in the text was causing grep to barf

Answer (score 28):

You can use the `strings` utility to extract the text content from any file and then pipe it through `grep`, like this: `strings file | grep pattern`.

Comment: Ideal for grepping log files that might be partly corrupted

Comment: yes, sometimes binary mixed logging also happens. This is good.

Comment: This will work with any UTF-8 file, or something like `--encoding` option should be specified? `-e S` [seems insufficient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17470569/is-there-strings-command-for-utf-8#comment107076175_17470689)

Answer (score 25):

#### GNU grep 2.24 RTFS

Conclusion: 2 and 2 cases only:

- `NUL`, e.g. `printf 'a\0' | grep 'a'`
- encoding error according to the C99 `mbrlen()`, e.g.:

  ```sh
  export LC_CTYPE='en_US.UTF-8'
  printf 'a\x80' | grep 'a'
  ```

  because `\x80` cannot be the first byte of an UTF-8 Unicode point: [UTF-8 - Description | en.wikipedia.org](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Description)

Those checks are only done up to the Nth byte of the input, where N = TODO (32KiB in one test system). If the check would fail after the Nth byte, the file is still considered a text file. ([mentioned by Stéphane Chazelas](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/19907/what-makes-grep-consider-a-file-to-be-binary/276028?noredirect=1#comment479845_276028)).

##### Only up to the first buffer read

So if a NUL or encoding error happens in the middle of a very large file, it might be grepped anyways.

I imagine this is for performance reasons.

E.g.: this prints the line:

```sh
printf '%10000000s\n\x80a' | grep 'a'
```

but this does not:

```sh
printf '%10s\n\x80a' | grep 'a'
```

The actual buffer size depends on how the file is read. E.g. compare:

```sh
export LC_CTYPE='en_US.UTF-8'
(printf '\n\x80a') | grep 'a'
(printf '\n'; sleep 1; printf '\x80a') | grep 'a'
```

With the `sleep`, the first line gets passed to grep even if it is only 1 byte long because the process goes to sleep, and the second read does not check if the file is binary.

##### RTFS

```sh
git clone git://git.savannah.gnu.org/grep.git 
cd grep
git checkout v2.24
```

Find where the stderr error message is encoded:

```sh
git grep 'Binary file'
```

Leads us to [`src/grep.c`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/grep.git/tree/src/grep.c?h=v2.24#n1498):

```c
if (!out_quiet && (encoding_error_output
                   || (0 <= nlines_first_null && nlines_first_null < nlines)))
  {
    printf (_("Binary file %s matches\n"), filename);
```

If those variables were well named, we basically reached the conclusion.

###### encoding_error_output

Quick grepping for `encoding_error_output` shows that the only code path that can modify it goes through [`buf_has_encoding_errors`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/grep.git/tree/src/grep.c?h=v2.24#n576):

```c
clen = mbrlen (p, buf + size - p, &mbs);
if ((size_t) -2 <= clen)
  return true;
```

then just [`man mbrlen`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/mbrlen.3.html).

###### nlines_first_null and nlines

[Initialized](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/grep.git/tree/src/grep.c?h=v2.24#n1380) as:

```c
intmax_t nlines_first_null = -1;
/* removed for brevity */
nlines = 0;
```

so when a null is found `0 <= nlines_first_null` becomes true.

TODO when can `nlines_first_null < nlines` ever be false? I got lazy.

### POSIX

Does not define binary options for [grep](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/grep.html), and GNU grep does not document it, so RTFS is the only way.

Comment: Impressive explication!

Comment: Note that the check for valid UTF-8 only happens in UTF-8 locales. Also note that the check is only done on the first buffer read from the file which for a regular file seems to be 32768 bytes on my system, but for a pipe or socket can be as small as one byte.  Compare `(printf '\n\0y') | grep y` with `(printf '\n'; sleep 1; printf '\0y') | grep y` for instance.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas "Note that the check for valid UTF-8 only happens in UTF-8 locales": do you mean about the `export LC_CTYPE='en_US.UTF-8'` as in my example, or something else? Buf read: amazing example, added to answer. You have obviously read the source more than me, reminds me of those [hacker koans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hacker_koan) "The student was enlightened" :-)

Comment: I didn't look into great detail either, but [did very recently](/a/275691)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I was not able to reproduce the UTF locale part of this with GNU grep 2.16.  `printf 'a\x80' | LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 grep a` did not warn, whereas changing `80` to `00` did warn.

Comment: @jrw32982 interesting. Maybe open up 2.16 and see if the `encoding_error_output` is there. Maybe it was added since.

Comment: @CiroSantilli巴拿馬文件六四事件法轮功 what version of GNU grep did you test against?

Comment: @jrw32982 2.24, same I opened source for. Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: @CiroSantilli巴拿馬文件六四事件法轮功 The grep 2.16 source looks substantially different than the grep 2.24 source. There is no `encoding_error_output`.  The checks are for a NUL in the first buffer or if there are "holes" in the file indicating a NUL character somewhere.  If `-z` is specified, then it checks instead for `\x80` (`\200`).

Comment: @jrw32982 thanks for input! What does a "hole" in the file mean?

Comment: @CiroSantilli巴拿馬文件六四事件法轮功 [sparse file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_file)

Comment: Dammit, the only answer that thoroughly and precisely addresses the questions is sits down here with 10% of the votes of the most voted one.

Comment: @Quasímodo https://cirosantilli.com/stack-overflow#image-stack-overflow-in-a-nutshell

Answer (score 8):

One of my text files was suddenly being seen as binary by grep:

```
$ file foo.txt
foo.txt: ISO-8859 text
```

Solution was to convert it by using `iconv`:

```
iconv -t UTF-8 -f ISO-8859-1 foo.txt > foo_new.txt
```

Comment: This happened to me as well. In particular, the cause was an ISO-8859-1-encoded non-breaking space, which I had to replace with a regular space in order to get grep to search in the file.

Comment: grep 2.21 treats ISO-8859 text files as if they are binary, add export LC_ALL=C before grep command.

Comment: @netawater Thanks! This is e.g. the case if you have something like Müller in a text-file. That's `0xFC` hexadecimal, so outside the range grep would expect for utf8 (up to `0x7F`). Check with printf 'a\x7F' | grep 'a' as Ciro describe above.

Answer (score 5):

The file `/etc/magic` or `/usr/share/misc/magic` has a list of sequences that the command `file` uses for determining the file type.

**Note** that binary may just be a fallback solution. Sometimes files with strange encoding are considered binary too.

`grep` on Linux has some options to handle binary files like `--binary-files` or `-U / --binary`

Comment: More precisely, encoding error according to C99's `mbrlen()`. Example and source interpretation at: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/276028/32558

Answer (score 2):

Actually answering the question "What makes grep consider a file to be binary?", you can use `iconv`:

```
$ iconv < myfile.java
iconv: (stdin):267:70: cannot convert
```

In my case there were Spanish characters that showed up correctly in text editors but grep considered them as binary; `iconv` output pointed me to the line and column numbers of those characters

In the case of `NUL` characters, `iconv` will consider them normal and will not print that kind of output so this method is not suitable

Answer (score 2):

One of my students had this problem. There is a bug in `grep` in `Cygwin`.  If the file has non-Ascii characters, `grep` and `egrep` see it as binary.

Comment: That sounds like a feature, not a bug. Especially given there is a command-line option to control it (-a / --text)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I used `vi -b [filename]` to see the added characters. I found the control characters `^@` and `^M`. Then in vi type `:1,$s/^@//g` to remove the `^@` characters. Repeat this command for `^M`.

Warning: To get the "blue" control characters press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>@</kbd>. Then save and exit vi.

Answer (score 1):

I also had this problem but in my case it was caused when a matched line is too long.

```
file myfile.txt
myfile.txt: UTF-8 Unicode text, with very long lines
```

`grep` would run through the entire file fine with many patterns but when a pattern matched a "very long line" it stopped with `Binary file myfile.txt matches`.

Adding `-a` also solves this problem but pre-parsing the file for NULL or other invalid chars would have no effect (there are none otherwise grep would not complete for other patterns). In this case the offending line had 25k+ characters!

What I don't understand is why it only happens when `grep` tries to return the line and not when it is processing it looking for other patterns.