# How to remove "binary data" from a text file (e.g. bash_history)?

Tags: grep, binary

Like discussed in questions like:

- "[How does grep decide that a file is binary?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/230397/24394)" or
- "[What makes grep consider a file to be binary?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/19907/24394)"

that grep might stop processing files it considers binary.

While this is normaly not a big problem, when searching text files, it has turned out, that sometimes some text files are "dirty", i.e. contain some binary data.

My specific case motivating this question is that somehow some binary data (to whatever is considered binary by grep, see questions cited), made its way into the `.bash_history` file, I would like to remove it.

How can I remove binary data from a text file?

More than just the removing binary data, I would appreciate to be able to have a look on what is the offending (to grep) binary data, as to avoid the removal of something needed/important.

Comment: same is happening actually to me. Have you find any good solution? Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

```
cat -v .bash_history > newbashhistory
```

Look at newbashhistory and decide if you like it

Answer (score 4):

One way to view the lines containing not-text data is:

```
perl -nle 'print if m/[^ -~\t\r]/' .bash_history | hexdump -C
```

basically print the line if it matches a character *not* (`^`) in the space to tilde range (the printable stuff, per a review of `ascii(7)`) and also not some other not-text-but-okay characters (newlines should be magically handled by the `-l` flag).

If the binary contents of those line looks okay to destroy, then you can delete them via something like:

```
perl -i.whoopsie -ple 's/[^ -~\t\r]//g' .bash_history
```

And then perhaps use

```
cmp -l .bash_history.whoopsie .bash_history
```

to verify that the correct binaries have been destroyed.

Comment: this works like a charm thank you