# grep returns "Binary file (standard input) matches" when trying to find a string pattern in file

Tags: files, grep, binary

I'm on Ubuntu and I typed `cat .bash_history | grep git` and it returned

> Binary file (standard input) matches

My `bash_history` does exist and there are many lines in it that starts with `git`.

What caused it to display this error and how can I fix it?

Comment: Whats the output of `file .bash_history` (`file ~/.bash_history`)?

Comment: the output is `.bash_history: data
`

Comment: for some reason this was just happening with my apache logs.  thanks for the q&a

Comment: very closely related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/19907/5510

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Presumably the file `.bash_history` starts with non-text data, hence `grep` is treating the file as binary. This is confirmed by the `file .bash_history` output:

```
.bash_history: data
```

You can read a few bytes from start to have a conforming view:

```
head -c1K .bash_history
```

Here I am reading first 1 KiB.

You can pipe the STDOUT to `hexdump`/`od` or similar.

---

As a side note, `grep` takes filename(s) as argument, so `cat` is useless here; try this:

```
grep git .bash_history
```

Comment: I'm still not sure how to solve the grep issue, `head -c1k .bash_history` read the first 38 lines of my .bash_history file. Everything was readable

Comment: @TatakaiWasumi Whats the output of `grep -a git .bash_history`?

Comment: That worked! I got everything I wanted from it. What does `-a` do?

Comment: @TatakaiWasumi `-a` makes `grep` to treat the file as binary.

Comment: that's weird, is there a way to convert my bash history back to a text file if grep thinks it's binary?

Comment: @TatakaiWasumi can you go through the file and check for any unusual string?

Comment: `-a` make `grep` process a binary file as if it were text.

Comment: `file` claims it's `data` yet...I don't see it: `$ head -c1K .bash_history |xxd
00000000: 7375 646f 2061 7074 2075 7064 6174 650a  sudo apt update.`

Answer (score 363):

You can use `grep -a 'pattern'`.

from [man grep](https://linux.die.net/man/1/grep) page:

> **-a, --text**
>       Process a binary file as if it were text; this is equivalent to the **--binary-files=text** option.

Comment: This has helped me when using the `-z` flag to match across several lines.

Comment: It has worked for me, but still weird because my file isn't a binary file.
[grid@serverdg2 trace]$ file listener.log
listener.log: data

Comment: It is enough, if your file has a single non-decodable character, and grep will fail (if not used with -a)

Answer (score 11):

This can be caused by null bytes in your bash history. Removing lines with null characters may resolve the issue. You can check for them using grep's Perl-regexp mode:

```
grep -Pa '\x00' .bash_history
```

[This post](https://superuser.com/questions/507267/how-to-grep-for-special-character-nul) has suggestions for non-unix systems.

Comment: This actually helped me find out why I was having the same problem.

Comment: Plus one from me too.

Comment: same as me, too

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem when I want to grep my `.bash_history`. (Little Note: I renamed my history, so that a new one was created. This new history was not treated as a binary.)

In @heemayls answer it is stated, that `grep` takes filenames and `cat` would be useless. This is not entirely true.
From `grep`s man page:

> If no files are specified, or if the file “-” is given, grep searches standard input.

So you could use `cat` and pipe it to `grep`. However this solves not the problem that `.bash_history` is treated as a binary. The only right thing is to use `grep -a` (Like in the answer from @AK_) whether you `grep` the history directly or with `cat` and a pipe.

---

```
cat .bash_history | grep -a git
```

or

```
grep -a git .bash_history
```

Answer (score 4):

Error is due to the data in the file being binary, you can use strings command to see the human readable (i.e. `strings`) part which you would normally search using `grep`

`strings data | grep -i whatever`

Comment: This does not address the first part of the question, i.e. "what causes the issue".