# Grep -n not working

Tags: grep

`grep -n [pattern] [file]` should return the line number and output of the line of my file.

However, `grep -n [my pw] /usr/share/wordlists/weakpass_3` is only returning

```
grep: /usr/share/wordlists/weakpass_3: binary file matches
```

The file exitsts and is readable by the user and the password is also in the wordlist.
`file /usr/share/wordlists/weakpass_3`
returns
`/usr/share/wordlists/weakpass_3: data`

How can I make grep output the line number with the line of the file?

Comment: Related: [What makes grep consider a file to be binary?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/19907/what-makes-grep-consider-a-file-to-be-binary)

Comment: updated question to include the output of `file /usr/share/wordlists/weakpass_3`

Comment: @UndercoverDog use `grep -a 'text' /yourpath`. Related: [grep returns "Binary file matches"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/335716/414186)

Comment: Add output of this command to your question (no comment here): `file /usr/share/wordlists/weakpass_3`

Comment: `grep` seems to interfere with at least one character in your file and then classifies it as data. A possible workaround might be: `strings /usr/share/wordlists/weakpass_3 | grep -n 'text'`

Answer (score 2):

Your `grep` (likely GNU `grep`) detects that the file may not be text and instead of printing the matching lines, it only tells you there's a match to avoid printing what may just be garbage.

To bypass that and print it nonetheless, you can add the `-a` option (a GNU extension).

Also note that `grep` by default matches regular expressions (the `re` in `grep`), you need `-F` to find substrings.

Also, arguments to executed commands are public knowledge on a system, so you shouldn't pass a password or any sensitive data to `grep` as argument unless `grep` happens to be a built-in of your shell (very few shells have `grep` builtin though).

So instead, assuming a shell where `printf` is builtin (most these days):

```
printf '%s\n' "$password" | grep -anFf - /usr/share/wordlists/weakpass_3
```

Where:

- `-a`: bypass the heuristic check for binary files
- `-F`: `F`ixed string search instead of regular expression matching
- `-f -`: takes the list of strings to search for from stdin (one per line)
- `-n`: report line numbers